# Creating a hard link of a directory in java for windows

Tags: java, windows, directory, hardlink

I've to create in a directory a hard link to a other directory in my java program. (so not a link to a file) 
I used https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html but it don't work. 
thanks for your help :)

```
private static void creatlink(Path newLink, Path target) throws IOException {
    try {
        Files.createLink(newLink, target);
    } catch (IOException x) {
        System.err.println(x);
        }
}
```

Comment: Error log would be nice. Use: x.printStackTrace();

Answer (score 2):

From the [exact same documentation that you linked to in the question](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/links.html):

> Hard links are generally not allowed on directories.

It really is that simple.  What you're trying to do just isn't possible on any operating system that I'm aware of.  (There's [some discussion here.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/why-are-hard-links-to-directories-not-allowed-in-unix-linux))